# Can an individual further aggravate a full tear of the gluteus minimus tendon (trochanter insertion)?

Tags: tendinopathy, hips

Can an individual further aggravate a full tear of the gluteus minimus tendon  (trochanter insertion)?

I would tend to think that if the gluteus minimus tendon is fully torn, then no force can be exercised on the gluteus minimus muscle anymore, and as a result  an individual cannot further aggravate a full tear of the gluteus minimus tendon. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3):

A torn muscle will not stagnate: it will attempt to heal itself, although this process can result in poor outcomes if the native structure isn’t well-aligned during healing (e.g. when surgical repair is required). As this repair process occurs, the tissue is unstable, and “re-aggravation” refers to interrupting healing by exerting stresses on the injured tissue that it can’t compensate for in its compromised state. This applies to full or partial tears of the gluteus minimus or any muscle, or any tissue in the body for that matter.

Comment: Thanks! "as this repair process occurs, the tissue is unstable" -> do you mean that the muscle will be reconnected to the bone through some very weak regenerated tendon tissue?

Comment: That’s correct. [This paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00402-010-1246-5.pdf) describes healing of full-thickness rotator cuff muscle tears in rats: “The subacromial space presented multiple adhesions of scar tissue to the acromion, the coraco-acromial ligament and the remaining rotator cuff.” However, it’s important to note that some partial and full-thickness muscle tears in humans won’t heal without surgical repair (but they will get worse, as mentioned [here](https://www.jshoulderelbow.org/article/S1058-2746(01)10756-1/fulltext)).

Comment: Very interesting studies, thanks for the additional information!